# Changing character encoding

Tags: ruby, character-encoding

I am having problems changing the encoding on a text file in Ruby 1.9.2p290.  I am getting the error ***invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)***.  The problem (I think) lies in the fact that the charset seems to be unknown.

From the command line if I do the following:

```
$ file test.txt
```

I get:

```
Non-ISO extended-ASCII English text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Or, alternatively, if I do:

```
$ file -i test.txt
```

I get:

```
test.txt: text/plain; charset=unknown
```

However, in Ruby if I do:

```
data = File.open("test.txt").read

puts data.encoding.name

puts data.valid_encoding?
```

I get:

```
UTF-8
false
```

Here's a simplified snippet of my code:

```
data = File.open("test.txt").read

data.encode!("UTF-8")

data.each_line do |line|

  newfile_data << line

end
```

Comment: Does the file contain any fancy characters? How have you created the file/what was it saved as?

Answer (score 9):

In ruby 1.9 every stream has 2 encodings associated with it - external and internal encoding.
External encoding is encoding of the text that you read from the stream (in your case this is encoding of the file). Internal encoding is the desired encoding for text that is read from the file.

If you do not set external/internal encoding for the stream then default external/internal encoding of the process will be used. If internal encoding is not specified then string read from the stream are tagged (not converted) with the external encoding (the same as `String.force_encoding`.

Most likely you have

```
Encoding::default_external # => Encoding:UTF-8
Encoding::default_internal # => nil
```

And your file is encoded in ASCII-based standard character encodings, NOT in UTF-8. 
Your Ruby code reads sequence of bytes from external source into UTF-8 string. And because your string contains `Non-ISO extended-ASCII English text` you get `data.valid_encoding? # => false`.

You need to set external encoding of your stream to the encoding of the file. For example if you have file in *cp 1251* encoding with text `файл`, then you need to read it with the following code:

```
data = File.open("test.txt", 'r:windows-1251').read    
puts data.encoding.name    # => windows-1251
puts data.valid_encoding?  # => true
```

or even specify both internal and external encoding:

```
data = File.open("test.txt", 'r:windows-1251:utf-8').read    
puts data.encoding.name    # => utf-8
puts data.valid_encoding?  # => true
```

Answer (score 3):

```
data = IO.read("test.txt", :encoding => 'windows-1252')
data = data.encode("UTF-8").gsub("\r\n", "\n")
```